# Error because of unexpected "}" - question in R. How to solve?

Tags: r, database, loops

```
for (i in 1:214)
{
  temp1 <- subset(perm2, perm2$isin == list[1+i])
  temp2 <- subset(temp1, temp1$Price != "NA")
  tempstart <- min(temp2$Time)
 if (is.na(tempstart)) 
   {
tempstart = "01/01/2020" else tempstart = tempstart
    }
 temp3 <- perm2[perm2$isin == list[1=i] & perm2$Time >= tempstart]
 perm3 <- rbind(perm3,temp3)
}
```

I am writing a function that binds a bunch of data together. 
Unfortunately some of my data is not working and I need to specify a date for na observations of date.

But then I get the unexpected } problem >> "Error: unexpected '}' in "}""

Can anyone please elucidate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` condition loop also wraps the `else` inside, instead it should end followed by `else`

```
 tempstart = "01/01/2020" else tempstart = tempstart
```

would be

```
 tempstart = "01/01/2020" 
  } else {tempstart <- tempstart}
```

---

Without a small reproducible example, it is not clear about the structure of the objects.  Considering the "list" as `list` and `NA` as real NA,

```
for(i in 1:214){ 
    temp1 <- subset(perm2, isin == list[[1+i]] & !is.na(Price))
    tempstart <- min(temp1$Time)
    if(is.na(tempstart)) {
       tempstart <- "01/01/2020"
     }
    temp3 <- perm2[perm2$isin == list[[i-i]] & perm2$Time >= tempstart,]
    perm3 <- rbind(perm3,temp3)

 }
```

Also, the `i + 1`, assumes that the `list` have length of 215 or else  when i is 214, there won't be corresponding element for list

Comment: for (i in 1:214){
  temp1 <- subset(perm2, perm2$isin == list[1+i])
  temp2 <- subset(temp1, temp1$Price != "NA")
  tempstart <- min(temp2$Time)
  if (is.na(tempstart)) {
    tempstart = "01/01/2020"
    } else {tempstart <- tempstart}
  temp3 <- perm2[perm2$isin == list[1=i] & perm2$Time >= tempstart]
  perm3 <- rbind(perm3,temp3)
}
This is where I am right now. any ideas?

Comment: @Rnovice there are some other issues `list[1=i]`

Comment: Yes aware of the creep up to 215

Comment: @Rnovice if you can show a small reproducible example, it is easier to test.  also, the `list[1 = i]` is not clear

Comment: Yes the list should be 1+i so i changed that. Thank you. at the moment i am running the code and seeing whether it works